# Maven dry run but with actual connection testing

Tags: maven, testing, deployment

Is it possible to use maven release:prepare --dry-run in some way that it still actually tries to connect to the deployment target? I mostly need it to validate that the connection is available, but not actually do anything or modify the current version number.

Comment: What do you mean by `deployment target`? remote repository?

Comment: @khmarbaise 'remote' only as in somuch it runs on a server we control in the next door building, but a different machine from where the command would run.

Comment: You didn't get my question. Are you just trying to deploy the artifacts to a remote repository or do you do a deployment on an application server (Wildfly, etc.)

Comment: @khmarbaise Ah, sorry. It's going onto a remote repository (from which it then goes on to an application server, but that's irrelevant here).

Comment: What do you need to test? If the deploy to the remote repository works?

Comment: @khmarbaise Whether it COULD work. Whether access rights are correctly set and there is a connection.